# Using VBA to Grab Stock Info from the Web

Tags: vba, stockquotes

I have been attempting to write a macro that grabs financial information from the internet and pastes it into my macro for further analysis. I have been trying to use a query from one of my existing connections (MSN stock quotes).

with my code (below) I have been able make the query pop up but what I can't figure out how to do is to enter anything into the box that pops up. What I'm basically looking for is how to (after the code I have listed below) tell excel to type in certain values into the box that pops up and click "OK" to run the query.

below is my code that initiates the query box asking for tickers

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "FINDER;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\QUERIES\MSN MoneyCentral Investor Stock Quotes.iqy" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "MSN MoneyCentral Investor Stock Quotes"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Sean, have a looksie at VB.NET as opposed to VBA - you'll find it much more conducive to things like this. As for good libraries for financial data - check out this library:

https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/